# Facebook app not working

Tags: ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch. The Facebook application was working fine until three days ago. When I start the Facebook app, it shuts down immediately. I tried restarting the phone but it's the same. I tried deleting the app and reinstalling, but it will not allow me to reinstall stating the app requires iOS 4.3.
How can I make this work? Why would it have all of a sudden stopped working?

Comment: Which OS version are you running on the iPod?

Answer (score 1):

Did you sync your iPod Touch with iTunes recently? An iOS device won't download newer versions of an app if they can no longer run on your current iOS version, but iTunes doesn't stick to that rule. So if the Facebook app was updated in iTunes, and then you synced with your iPod Touch, it may have been updated to a version that it can't run, hence the immediate quitting.

You can verify this by going to **Settings → General → Usage** and tap on the app under the storage setting. You'll see a version number, and you can Google that to see if you have a version that supports old iOS or not.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue with an ipod i bought my other son it wouldnt let me download facebook it said i needed to update my ipod 4th gen from 6.... to 7.....
but when i tried to update the ipod it said it was already updated,
my older son has an ipod 4th gen already with facebook installed so when i logged into itunes i could see all his apps including facebook
i then logged out of his apple id and i logged in with my other sons apple id (son with no facebook)
all the previous apps were still there so i clicked update facebook it downloaded and then went onto the ipod it asked if i wanted to download the older version so i clicked yes and it worked i hope this helps !
Edit